# why the first number element stored in an array is wrong in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const arr = [0123, 1456];
console.log(arr);
```

The result is `[ 83, 1456 ]`, but I think it should be `[0123, 1456]`.

The first element is wrong. I don't know why.

Comment: In javascript a number beginning with `0` followed by a digit lower than `8` or `9` is interpreted as an octal number therefore `0123` (octal) becomes 3*8^0 + 2*8^1 + 1*8^2 = 3 + 16 + 64 = `83` (decimal)

Answer (score -2):

Numbers starting with zero are [octal integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). You might want to use `123` as your first member of the array.